# PHP file works locally, but not on server

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone

I'm currently developing a mobile app on windows phone which requires me to send a request to a PHP file located on a server.

I'm running into an issue where the request throws an error when on the server, but doesn't when I change the code to page the local PHP file. Any ideas why?

Here's my request code:

```
     string sendString = "";
        sendString += "&lat=" + (App.Current as App).mapCenter.Latitude;
        sendString += "&lng=" + (App.Current as App).mapCenter.Longitude;
        sendString += "&address=" + (App.Current as App).locationAddress;
        if (checkNumber(CountryCode.Text, AreaCode.Text, Number.Text))
        {
            sendString += "&phone=" + CountryCode.Text + "" + AreaCode.Text + "" + Number.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Phone number invalid");
        }
        if (checkEmail(email.Text))
        {
            sendString += "&email=" + email.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email");
        }
        sendString += "device=WindowsPhone";
        sendString += (bool)prefsms.IsChecked ? "&contactMethod=sms" : "&contactMethod=email";
        ListPickerItem selectedItem = (ListPickerItem)ServiceType.SelectedItem; //Cast listpickeritem into String
        string content = (string)selectedItem.Content;
        sendString += "&serviceType=" + content;
        sendString += "&version=2.0";
        sendString += "&language=" + CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        (App.Current as App).watcher.Stop();
        sendData = sendString;


        if ((checkNumber(CountryCode.Text, AreaCode.Text, Number.Text)) && (checkEmail(email.Text)))
        {
            //Send data to server 
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/test.php");
            myRequest.Method = "POST";
            myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(RequestCallBack), myRequest);
        }
        else
        {
        }

private void RequestCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncresult)
{
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = asyncresult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        Stream dataStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asyncresult);
        //Avoid trashing procedure
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(dataStream);
            writer.Write(sendData);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            //Expect a response
            myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseCallBack), myRequest);
        });

    }
  private void ResponseCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncresult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = asyncresult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncresult);
        // Avoid trashing the procedure
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            // Retrieve response stream
            Stream responseStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            // Show response
            responseTxt = reader.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show("" + responseTxt);
        });

    }
```

I'm sending a string to the server, and the server's PHP code looks like this (the test php is exactly the same):

```
require_once("includes/globals.php");

$vars = ($PRODUCTION)?$_POST:$_REQUEST;

$MINIMUM_VERSION = 2.0;
function validServiceType($type)
{
return $type == "taxi" || $type == "ladies" || $type == "limo" || $type ==   "handicap";
}

if(!isset($vars['version']) || ((float)$vars['version']) < $MINIMUM_VERSION)
{
echo "oldVersion";
}
elseif(isset($vars['lat'], $vars['lng'], $vars['phone'], $vars['language']))
{
     /*do stuff */
if($data['contactMethod'] == "email" && $data['email'] == "")
{
    echo "invalid";
    die();
}
if(DB_AddHail($data))
    echo "processing";
else if (($company = DB_GetReferralTaxi($data['lat'], $data['lng'], $data['serviceType'])))
{
    /*do some more stuff*/
}
else
    echo "sorry";
}
else
{
echo "invalid";
}

?>
```

I keep getting an OldVersion error but I've set the version number to be 2.0 already...any ideas as to what's going on?

UPDATE: I've now been able to figure the source of the problem; the HttpWebRequest isn't sending any data over to the server at all; my $_POST is just an empty array. Any ideas as to why?

UPDATE 2: The error I was getting is error 302 ("my URI I was using was just http:// instead of https://). However after changing the protocol to https://, it still doesn't work. Is my code incorrect for that part?

Comment: is this part the same in your code or not?`
return $type == "taxi" || $type == "ladies" || $type == "limo" || $type ==   handicap";` if yes, try removing `"` from end of it!

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo on my part; the handicap is already fixed in the actual live version

Comment: _"my $_POST is just an empty array"_ - how do you see that? Does the file get requested, according to the logs? And with what method, and what was the response?

Comment: I added a "echo $_POST['version']"  and a "echo $vars['version']" line  but the echo just gave an empty string. I'm sending the data through using the C# code as described above; and the server response is "OldVersion" (because $vars['version'] isn't set to anything).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try, immediately before the line starting with if(!isset($vars['version']), adding:

```
echo "version: " . $vars['version']; 
exit;
```

See if it outputs anything to the browser. It might be that the version of php you're using doesn't like the $vars = ($PRODUCTION)?$_POST:$_REQUEST; syntax, and you might have to manually go through and so something like

```
$vars['version']=$_POST['version']; 
$vars['somethingElse']=$_POST['somethingElse']
```

etc...

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, and $vars['version'] gives me "2.0", so I really don't understand why it's not working

Comment: Then I'm sorry to say I'm not sure either. I copied and pasted your exact code onto a live production server and it works perfectly... Good luck! Hopefully someone can be more help.

Comment: Haha thanks for your help; I think I'll try re-coding it using a different method (using WebClient instead of HttpWebRequest) and see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your on 5.4.3 and run your script with phpinfo(); to check. Try change you're PHP/C# to receive/send GET requests instead of POST requests.

That way you can atleast test to see when you send the php script a request from the browser for example http://yourdomain.com/script.php?name=John+Smith&Age=23, if you're getting expected results. Download https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ to check how the headers are working from the browser point of view when you're checking the results.

Comment: @docaholic Because your running off the localhost have you tried changing the URL your going too? from "http://localhost/" to "http://WORKSTATION_GROUP.USERNAME.local/test.php" (open command prompt and run ping localhost.).. Something tells me your C# code can't find the localhost, is the localhost declared as an enviroment variable in your C IDE? also with GET request set your content type to "text/html" and see if that helps.

Comment: Hmm...I still get the same error even with GET. Also, the server is set up so that it deals with POST requests only; I know the server works as well, because I have a website with the same service, and that functions perfectly.

Comment: Mmm I'll have a look into it later can you provide a pastebin of globals.php?

Comment: yeah sure: http://pastebin.com/XffmSYVt

it's not very useful, as all it does is connect to another PHP file that connects to a database..and unfortunately, i don't have access to the database.php file